# Representing $\frac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ as a square of a quadratic surd

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, real-numbers

How can I represent $\frac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ as square of a quadratic surd?
Actually, I was solving a question where $\frac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ was converted to $(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^2$. How did the solution writer think of it?

Comment: $\sqrt{\frac{7 + 3\sqrt 5}{2}}$

Comment: @SomeStrangeUser: I think you missed the point.

Comment: Sorry, Didn't read it right the first time. we can set $(a+b\sqrt{5})^2=\frac{3}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{5}$. Then, solve for $a$ and $b$. This gets us: $$a^2 + 5b^2 = \frac{3}{2},\ 2ab = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can set $(a+b\sqrt{5})^2=\frac{3}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{5}$. Then, solve for rational $a$ and $b$.

Comparing the terms we obtain: $$a^2 + 5b^2 = \frac{3}{2},\ \ \ 2ab = \frac{1}{2}$$ Solving for $a$ and $b$, we get $a=b=\frac{1}{2}$ or  $a=b=-\frac{1}{2}$, thus the two possible squares are: $$ \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2,\ \ \ \left(\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $1+\frac{1}{\phi}=\phi$, where $\phi$ is the [golden ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio). Mathematicians are *very* familiar with the basic properties of this number.

Comment: So you mean had it not been related to the golden ratio, it would have been difficult to convert like that?

Comment: @shaurya: I think David's answer is completely irrelevant! Why did you accept it?

Comment: I didn't mean to...Coz he hasn't answered my comment...

Comment: This answer is not irrelevant at all...from that identity you find that $\phi^2 = \phi + 1$ (although granted it is easier to start with this equation as defining $\phi$) and the RHS is exactly the number we are wanting the square root of.

Comment: Having it in the form $\phi^2 = \phi + 1$ certainly makes more sense for this problem than $1 + \frac{1}{\phi} = \phi$...

Comment: @user92774 Absolutely. That's what my hint is supposed to be hinting at.

Comment: Indeed, I think it's better that the answer isn't just spoonfed, just saying that it may initially seem useless to OP the way you stated it :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to 'complete the square'

$\frac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{2} =$

$ \frac{6 + 2 \sqrt{5}}{4} =$

$ \frac{1 + 2 \sqrt{5} + 5}{4} =$

$\frac{(1 + \sqrt{5})^2}{4} =$

$(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} )^2$

So

$\sqrt{ \frac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2} } = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} $

The other root is obvious by inspection , $ - \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} $

Now , as an exercise , can you do the same procedure to derive the other root?

Hint: You need to place a minus sign in an appropriate position.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$ is the golden ratio.

It is the solution to the quadratic equation $x^2=x+1$

The solution writer was probably familiar with this number.

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: $\frac{3+\sqrt 5}{2} = \frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}+1$

Comment: But how is your answer supposed to explain how to find the square root of $\frac{3+\sqrt 5}{2}$?

Comment: @TonyK Because it's equal to the square of the golden ratio, and so it's square root is the golden ratio. See my answer.

Comment: So if you know that it's equal to the square of the golden ratio, then you can work out that its square root is the golden ratio? That's actually not very helpful.

Comment: The OP wanted to understand the thought process of the "solution writer." That's what I had to offer, sorry.